# How to replace a invoked java class with it modifed version which has the same name?

Tags: java, runtime, classloader, reload

Suppose I have a `Driver` class and two `A` classes (one is default and the other is a modified version) to run, how can I realize that invoke a same `Driver` but have different outputs? The biggest problem there is that the the default `A` and `Driver` are loaded together with classpath. The example code is here:

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.foo();
    }
}
```

The default `A`:

```
public class A {
    public void foo() {
       System.out.println("Original A."); 
    }
}
```

The modified `A`:

```
public class A {
    public void foo() {
       System.out.println("Modified A!"); 
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
    @Test
    public void trialOnLoadModified() throws Exception {
        String testLoadPath = "src/test/resources/test-load";
        String testLoadModPath = "src/test/resources/test-load-modified";
        // Load from parent loader.
        MyClassLoader parentLoader = new MyClassLoader(testLoadPath); // Simulate AppClassLoader
        Class<?> driver = parentLoader.loadClass("Driver");
        invokeMain(driver);
        // Load from modified loader?
        Modifiedloader = new ModifiedLoader(testLoadModPath, parentLoader);
        loader.loadClass("A");
        Class<?> driver1 = loader.loadClass("Driver");
        invokeMain(driver1);
    }

    private void invokeMain(Class<?> mainClass) throws Exception {
        Method main = mainClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);
        main.invoke(null, (Object) new String[]{});
    }
```

The expected outputs are:

```
Original A.
Modified A!
```

but are:

```
Original A.
Original A.
```

Is it possible to reload a class? Or, will it work if I move some classes from `AppClassLoader` down to a costumized class? Like below:

```
AppClassLoader (loading Driver) 
+--- MyClassLoader1 (Loading Default A)
+--- MyClassLoader2 (Loading Modified A)
```

Code of `ModifiedLoader`:

```
public class ModifiedLoader extends URLClassLoader {

    /**
     * Cache the modified class once load.
     */
    private final Map<String, Class<?>> cache = new HashMap<>();

    //... Some constructors

    /**
     * Load modified class if the path is in given url. This method
     * break parent dispatch mechanism.
     *
     * @param name class name
     * @return modified class if in given url, else load from parent.
     *
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException if loading class failed.
     */
    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // Look up and load classes from cache first.
        if (cache.containsKey(name))
            return cache.get(name);

        // If class not cached, load it from given urls in prior.
        String internalName = name.replace('.', '/');
        String path = internalName.concat(".class");
        byte[] bytesToLoad = null;
        // Travers given url. Generally only on url.
        for (URL url : getURLs()) {
            FileInputStream fis;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(new File(url.getFile(), path));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // Cannot find class at given urls, continue to next
                continue;
            }
            // Reaching here means we find target class at given urls.
            try {
                bytesToLoad = fis.readAllBytes();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                String msg = String.format(
                    "Failed when reading bytes to load modified class %s!", name);
                throw new ClassNotFoundException(msg, e);
            }
            // No mater how the result of reading bytes is, jump out as
            // it is not possible to find another matched url.
            break;
        }

        // Reach here means modified  class has been found at and read properly.
        if (bytesToLoad != null) {
            Class<?> loadedClass;
            try {
                loadedClass = defineClass(name, bytesToLoad, 0, bytesToLoad.length);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                // Generally LinkageError. Thrown if a class is loaded repeatedly.
                String msg = String.format(
                    "Failed when loading class %s, dispatch to parent", name);
                throw new ClassNotFoundException(msg, e);
            }
            if (loadedClass != null) {
                // Update cache.
                cache.put(name, loadedClass);
                // Define modified class before dispatching to parent.
                return loadedClass;
            }
        }

        // Dispatch to parent loader.
        return super.loadClass(name);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you want to do this?

Comment: the relevant part is the `loadClass`method implementation

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer Well, I just have several versions of a same class to execute at runtime. The example code are a simplified version of my requirement.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer I used to realize my requirement by breaking parent dispatching mechism and reloading the  modified ``A`` together with the ``Driver``, but it turns out that things could go wrong at some cases. So I wander whether there are better solutions.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish, and why?

Comment: @JosephMcCarthy I trying to run two classes with same name. They are different version of a same class, and I'd like to compare their outputs. Both of these two methods are executed by a ``Driver``.

Comment: Why not create two classes - A1 and A2?